# How should I collaborate with developers who use Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, git, vim

I joined a project written in C++ in which the original developer used Xcode as an IDE. However, I would rather not use Xcode myself and instead use vim. The original developer is still active in the project, so he will continue to use Xcode. In order to collaborate on the project, I'm putting the project under version control, specifically git. However, I feel that any Xcode-related files are not pertinent to the actual project and therefore should not be in the repository. Am I wrong in my thinking? If I exclude Xcode-related files, how should Xcode developers manage this project? Perhaps a more general question is how should I collaborate on a version-controlled project in which some developers use Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to include all relevant, non-recreatable project files in the repository. The fact that not everyone needs all of them doesn't matter. It's common to put the project files for different IDEs in separate directories and reference the source from a central location, but that's up to you.

As an alternative, you could use something like CMake, which will create different types of project for you (including XCode projects) from a single script - you then check that script into the repository and have each developer create project files from it locally.

Comment: +1, especially for the suggestion of CMake or other buildsystem generators. That's what one *should* be using when different developers use different IDEs/buildsystems.